# NumberFormatException on Integer input after previous Long input

Tags: java, exception, netbeans, input, error-handling

I am receiving a `NumberFormatException` when I called for an `Integer` input after previously calling for a `Long` input. Below is my code snippet

```
            System.out.print("Student ID: ");
            studentID = sc.nextLong();
            System.out.print("Student Number: ");
            studName= Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

The error output are as follow

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
Student Name:   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:592)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at student.StudentClient.main(StudentClient.java:68)
Java Result: 1
```

May I know how can I resolve this error?

---

I have using `sc.nextInt()` instead. However, at the beginning of my code:

```
        System.out.println("\nMENU 1-QUIT / 2-ADD STUDENT");
        option = option = sc.nextInt();

        if (option == 1) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if (option == 2) {
            studentIndex++;
            studentList[studentIndex] = new Student();
            System.out.print("Student Title (Mr/Mrs): ");
            studentTitle = sc.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Student First Name: ");
            firstName = sc.nextLine();
```

The output from the above code skipped 1x input. Which makes it:

```
Student Title: Student First Name:
```

Comment: You need to call nextInt(), not nextLine()

Comment: What is the sc variable?

Comment: @qtips sorry for the sc, it is my scanner object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the call to nextLong() reads the next long number, but not the newline character after it. So, when you call next line you get back the blank line from the end of the number you just read up until the newline. For example, if I do this:

```
System.out.println("'" + sc.nextLong() + "'");
System.out.println("'" + sc.nextLine() + "'");
System.out.println("'" + sc.nextLine() + "'");
```

... and enter numbers like 42 & 63 I will get printed:

```
'42'
''
'63'
```

You need to consistently use either nextLong() or nextLine(), but not mix them.

Comment: Thank you @BarrySW19. I am obligated to use `Long` type for `studentID`variable though

Comment: You can do the same as for int: studentID = Long.parseLong(sc.nextLine());

Comment: Omg thank you @BarrySW19. Your answer above is exactly what helped me. Thank you!